# How to get size of c# windows forms application at runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms

When we use `this.Width` and `this.Height` to get size of a form they get the width and height before run.

I want to know can i get the width and height of my application (The main form) at runtime? I mean after resizing the form or maximizing the form at runtime?

For example I have a main form with a sub form inside it, and a popupControl1 inside the sub form.
 So I want to change the size of the popupControl1 according to the size of the main form

i tried to do this:

```
popupControl1.Width = Convert.ToInt32(this.Width / 1.3);
popupControl1.Height = Convert.ToInt32(this.Height / 1.2);
```

but it dosn't work because `this.Width` and `this.Height` gets the width and height befor running the application, so I may want to change the size of the application at runtime by resizing it or the application may be maximized.
I also replaced `this.Width` and `this.Height` with `this.Parent.Width` and `this.Parent.Height` to get the size of the main form but they also didn't work because `this.parent` returned `null`

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't seem to be giving consistent or accurate information. What is "subForm" in that first screenshot and what is its relevance? As for your claim about the `Height` and `Width` properties, it is false. They will both return the current height and width of the form. That should be clear from debugging.

Comment: Your application is not DpiAware. You'll get *virtualized* measures. -- In both your screenshots, compare the *blurriness* of your Form with sharp appearance of Visual Studio's UI in the background. VS is a DpiAware application.

Comment: @user18387401 that `subForm` is a form inside another form I have used mdiparent property to do that

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.mdiparent?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: So what values are you actually trying to get? The MDI parent or the MDI child? It's notable that you didn't mention MDI anywhere in your question. If you have code in the MDI child form and you want to access the MDI parent form then you use the `MdiParent` property, not the `Parent` property. They may well be similar but they are unlikely to be the same, especially for the height.

Comment: There is event ParentChanged on which you can get the parent control when it is fired at runtime. But the size of the parent still differs from the size of the main form